# Is it efficient to use lua to store game data?

Tags: xml, database, cocos2d-iphone, lua, game-engine

I'm new to lua and I'm wondering, is it efficient to use lua to store game data (such as monster's description, spells).

My problem is, 
when I try to create a monster object every second, I have to run the lua file and get the data repeatedly, 
which I think may be not efficient.

Before I try to use lua, I use XML to store data.
At the beginning of gameplay, I read the "monster.xml" file once, and keep it in the memory, and every time I need to create a monster, I just refer to it.
Is this XML approach more efficient than the lua one ? Or are there other better solutions?

Thanks !

Comment: You might get better answers to this question on our sister site, http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/.

Answer (score 5):

Why not read the Lua file only once, store the data in memory and copy it whenever needed?

Or, if (some of) the data doesn't change, you don't even need to copy it; just have all the monsters of that type refer to the same copy of the data.

Comment: Thanks! It is a great help. But I implement all the monsters as a single class, what's different between them is only the data and appearance. Therefore, I may need another way to go.

Comment: You could just store a reference / index to the monster data in each monster instance.

Answer (score 3):

If you load the Lua file via `lua_load()`, you get a compiled chunk as a Lua function.

So all file reading and parsing happens only once. Running this function and reading the results from the Lua state comes with it's own cost, but should be faster than getting data out of an XML structure, I guess.

Answer (score 3):

1. Load X from disk then read from memory when needed.
2. Load X from disk every time the data is needed.

#1 will be faster than #2 for any value of X (XML, Lua).

You're comparing #1(X=XML) with #2(X=Lua) which is an apples to oranges comparison.

If you prefer to use Lua as your data storage format -- for whatever reason (more concise, more flexible, ect.) -- there's no reason it can't be just as fast as using XML for the same purpose, assuming you treat the loaded data the same.

Assuming you're using Lua just as a means of loading *data* (and not behaviors), which it looks like you're doing, you should be pulling the data out into some structured data types anyway. The *source* of that data (XML, Lua, whatever) shouldn't really matter to the program once the data is slurped in.